# Service Creation failed AWS ECS Service with elastic inference accelerator (EIA)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, gpu

I am trying to create a service in my ECS cluster to run a task that uses elastic inference accelerator (EIA). However, when I try to create the service, I get the following error:

[image]

I have read the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elastic-inference/latest/developerguide/elastic-inference.pdf.pdf), and I understand there cannot be more than 5 accelerators in the same EC2 intance, and thus I have created a brand new EC2 for this.

But I still have the issue. If i remove the EI accelerator from the task definition, everything works fine.
My task defintion reference looks like this:

```
"resourceRequirements": [
        {
          "type": "InferenceAccelerator",
          "value": "device-gpu2"
        }
```

And in the container definition:

```
"eia": "device-gpu2"
```

**PS:** I have also double checked that my cloudwatch log groups have been created. I have several other EC2 instancers that work perfectly with the same config, so this is quite wierd, and I am positive it must be a limit issue, but with the wrong error message from the AWS console.

I have another EC2 instance that has 5 accelerators attached through ECS, and it works fine. Do you have any idea please?